# Azure functions resultcode in monitor

Tags: python-3.x, logging, azure-functions

I've been trying to get my logging output in order so I'd be able to fix any errors resulting from the Function working improperly. But all the logging says is ResultCode 0.

[image: Monitor resultcode]

As I looked at the initial examples of the docs I thought maybe i am missing a return, just like here [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=python). But I am misunderstanding how it works, because when I add them they only generate errors. They can be found in below snippet where I return the statuscode to the output binding.

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "mytimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 */10 * * * *"
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "direction": "out",
      "type": "http"
    }
  ]
}
```

**init**.py

```
def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest)-> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Getting pre-requisite data from Azure RM and CosmosDB ...')
    azure_nsg_list = get_full_nsg_list()
    cosmosdb_nsg_entities_list = get_list_of_entities()
    nsg_stack_reference_list = get_nsg_number_references()
    logging.info('Checking for unmanaged Network Security Groups ..')
    unmanaged_nsg_list = [item for item in azure_nsg_list if item not in cosmosdb_nsg_entities_list]

    if unmanaged_nsg_list:
        logging.info('Unmanaged NSGs found, adding to CosmosDB ..')
        for nsg in unmanaged_nsg_list:
            logging.info('Adding NSG %s ..')
            create_azure_table_entity()
        logging.info('Finished adding to CosmosDB ..')
        return func.HttpResponse("All found NSGs have been added to CosmosDB.", status_code=200)
    else:
        logging.info('No unmanaged NSGs found ...')
        return func.HttpResponse("No unmanaged NSGs found ...", status_code=101)
```

In the end i want to be able to get alerting on the moments when my function would actually give an error 4xx.
Is there some way I can get the ResultCodes to show the actual statuscode of the code? I have three functions, the other two have eventhub inputs.

Probably also important, this is my host.json:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
  },
  "extensions": {
    "eventHubs": {
        "batchCheckpointFrequency": 1,
        "eventProcessorOptions": {
            "maxBatchSize": 10,
            "prefetchCount": 20
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I actually there are other things I am missing, as the metrics are also not showing all the metrics which these logs should be based on. For example:
[image: metrics0]
[image: metrics1]
[image: metrics2]

Answer (score 0):

We can check all the logging.info messages from Application Insights. Make sure that Applications Insights are enabled for Function App.

Steps to get the log information: Application Insights (Our function App) -> Performance -> Select “Overall” under “Operation Name” column -> Select Function Name from the under “All” logs -> Click on “View all telemetry”

Here we will be able to see the message, have a look at below screenshot for reference from my function message:

[image: LogInfoScreenshot]

My Python code:

[image: CodeScreenshot]

Coming to 4XX error, mostly we’ll be getting 403 errors while running the function app.

We need to check two points here:

1. Need to make sure that we add all the values from Local.Settings.json file to Application settings (FunctionApp -> Configuration -> Application Settings)
2. Check for CORS. Try adding “*” (Any request made against a storage resource when CORS is enabled must either have a valid authorization header or must be made against a public resource.)

Comment: Hi @SaiKarri-MT thanks for the reply. My host.json has applicationinsight enabled and all the settings from my local.settings.json are in the Function App configuration. Yet I don't see any http4XX or 2XX metrics showing up in the application insight. Which i think is a result of missing something. I also don't know anything about CORS, but I'm not accessing any type of website or anything. The functions run independently based on events, or a scheduled timer. No resources are being accessed.